# Django - Datetime object with strftime not giving correct time

Tags: django, python-2.7, datetime, strftime

A datetime object from the database is in this format - `2016-04-14 20:30:00.000000`

Here is how I change it to a string:

```
>>> day.trade_datetime.strftime("%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S")
2016-14-04 00:00:00
```

I want the time to show correctly.

**models.py**

```
...
trade_datetime = models.DateTimeField(null=False, blank=False,
    verbose_name="Trade Date Time")
```

Here is a the datetime object:

```
>>> print day.trade_datetime
2016-04-14 00:00:00+00:00
```

Comment: Are you sure that you're fetching a `datetime` object and not a `date` object? Please post the model code that is associated with `day`.

Comment: Added it above @solarissmoke

Comment: Difficult to see what's going on with the info you provide here. What happens if you just `print day.trade_datetime`?

Comment: Can you display the output of `day.trade_datetime` without `strftime`.?

Comment: So the datetime object doesn't contain a value for minutes/hours... What makes you think the database does contain non-zero values for minutes/hours?